# How to display the output of a program both to a file and to the console(stdout)?

Tags: c, io-redirection

Say I have the following program that simply outputs "Hello World":

```
//DEMO.c
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
printf("HELLO World");
}
```

Now I want to display it both to the screen and to a file `output.txt`.So I enter the following command in the command prompt(I use CodeBlocks on Windows XP and have configured it to work on command prompt as well):

`demo.exe>>output.txt>>stdout`

It doesn't work!!! Please tell me how to do it,ie how to output the same thing that I see on my screen(When i run the program),simultaneously to a text file?

Comment: you could do it in the program itself right? command for different consoles might be different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define my_fprintf(fp,...)  do{fprintf(fp, __VA_ARGS__);fprintf(stdout, __VA_ARGS__);}while(0)

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    FILE *fp;

    fp=fopen("output.txt","w");//or filename from argv[1]

    my_fprintf(fp, "hello world by %s\n", argv[0]);

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to download a `tee` command for Windows. `tee` is a UNIX/Linux command that copies the standard input to standard output and also outputs to a file. Then, you can do this:

```
demo.exe | tee output.txt
```

[Here is one port of `tee`](http://code.google.com/p/wintee/) for Windows.

Comment: Or use a nicer environment like cygwin of course, which already has tee and all the usual *nix goodies...

Comment: @suspectus No way to do it in standard C?We are not asking for much here.We only want the output that we see on the screen to be saved to a file as well.

Comment: You can do it in your C program, but that's the "wrong" way - this kind of thing should be handled on the command line, not in the code.